# Unable to Cross Compile Kernel on Android

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I have a android project, I am able to compile standalone Linux kernel in Android using below command:

```
cd #kernel-source#

make  ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=/**/android/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin/aarch64-linux-android- -j20
```

But when I tried to compile complete Android, I got below error:

```
'asm/types.h' No such file or directory
```

What is happening when I compile complete Android?

Comment: please provide the command sequence you are using to compile complete android

Comment: source build/envsetup.sh , lunch 32, make flashfiles